# How to using css loader with react component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I am able to use webpack and css loader to produce a css file and js file when I compile a parent component where I import a css file. But if I do not import a css file in parent component but in a child component, and have webpack translate the parent component file, there's no css file produced. The problem is, there are some css files I only want to import in child component, but it seems that css loader does not allow me to doe this?

ex:

```
//parent.js
import React from 'react';
import Child from './child.js'

export class Parent extends React.Component(){
    render(){
        return <div><Child/></div>
    }
}

//child.js
import React from 'react';
import styleSheet from './a.css';

export class Child extends React.Component(){
    render(){
        return <div className = {styleSheet.example}>hi</div>
    }
}
```

currently my webpack configuration looks something like this.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: 'parent.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'parentBundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.css']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
         test: /\.js$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: [
             {
               loader: 'css-loader',
               query: {
                 localIdentName: '[hash:8]',
                 modules: true
               }
             }
           ]
         })
       }
     ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'testing.css',
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: have you tried `import styleSheet from './a.css'`? if you avoid `./` you are looking for that module on `node_modules`

Comment: yes I did. I was just writing an example. So is this suppose to work with this setting?

Comment: yeah buddy your configuration is right, it should be working. Do you have this in a repo? maybe you can share it so I can help you better